# Checking whether a given polynomial is reducible or irreducible.

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> We're given the polynomial $x^{2}-2$ , and we need to prove that it's irreducible in $\mathbb Q$ but reducible in $\mathbb R$.

Writing the polynomial as $(x^{2}-2) = 1.(x^{2}-2)$ ,

$(x^{2}-2)$ can't be a unit in $Q[x]$ whereas $1$ is a unit in $Q[x]$ , hence the given polynomial is irreducible in $Q$.

Can't we apply the same argument for $R$ also ? Since rationals are contained in reals , won't that imply that it's irreducible in $R$ too ?

But we have to prove that it's reducible in $R$ , am I missing something ?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I hope OP is not being asked to prove $x^2+1$ is reducible over the reals. Maybe $x^2-2$ was meant.

Comment: I"m so sorry.. It's $(x^{2} -2)$. I've made a correction.

Comment: Are you happy with the answer you have received? Do you still have any unresolved issues?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Satisfied. Thank you very much. I read your comment below , I was only looking for a hint to proceed and I got that with the answer below . Thanks fo your concern. @GerryMyerson

Comment: So if you know how to do the question now, let me encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer. Then you can accept your own answer, and that will remove this question from the "Unanswered" list.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments said, $x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1)$, which is *reducible* in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, clearly.  So, I am going to assume that you mean $x^2+1$, which is not reducible in $\mathbb{R}$, since $\text{discriminate}(x^2+1) = 0^2 - 4(1)(1) = -4 < 0$.

But, to show that it is not reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, suppose that it is, then it is the product of two degree one polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$; I.e. 
$$x^2+ 0x +1 = (x - a)(x -b) =x^2 -(a+b)x + ab $$

Implying $a+b = 0$, and $ab = 1$. Further, $a = -b$ implying $ab = (-b)(b) = 1$, a contradiction.

EDIT: Note, similar logic holds in showing that $x^2-2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$. To show that it is reducible in $\mathbb{R}$ it is enough to show that $x^2-2 =(x-\sqrt{2})(x +\sqrt{2})$, noting that $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ and that $0 \neq \text{deg}(x \pm \sqrt{2}) = 1 < \text{deg}(x^2-2) = 2.$

Comment: But it seems OP has been asked to prove some polynomial (we can only guess which polynomial) is irreducible over the rationals but reducible over the reals. So we're probably not talking about $x^2+1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you're probably right. But, maybe OP miss-typed, in which case I hope this is just useful knowledge.

Comment: I've made a correction. It's $x^{2} - 2$. To prove that its reducible in $R$ we are to write $x^{2} - 2 = (x- \sqrt{2})(x+ \sqrt{2})$ and conclude that these are non units in R[x]. Am I correct ?

Comment: @User9523 Check the edit.

Comment: "similar logic"? For $x^2+1$, the logic is that squares of reals are never negative. For $x^2-2$, the logic is squares of rationals are never 2. Not all that similar, I think. OP has to prove $\sqrt2$ is irrational, or apply Eisenstein, or the Rational Roots Theorem, or something.